# How to insert data into this Entity object?

Tags: java, entity

This is my Entity class

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "RESERVATION")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Reservation.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Reservation r"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Reservation.findByReservationid", query = "SELECT r FROM Reservation r WHERE r.reservationid = :reservationid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Reservation.findByReservationdate", query = "SELECT r FROM Reservation r WHERE r.reservationdate = :reservationdate")})
public class Reservation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "RESERVATIONID")
    private String reservationid;
    @Column(name = "RESERVATIONDATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date reservationdate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "loginid")
    private List<Reservation> reservationList;
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOGINID", referencedColumnName = "LOGINID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Reservation loginid;

    public Reservation() {
    }

    public Reservation(String reservationid) {
        this.reservationid = reservationid;
    }

    public String getReservationid() {
        return reservationid;
    }

    public void setReservationid(String reservationid) {
        this.reservationid = reservationid;
    }

    public Date getReservationdate() {
        return reservationdate;
    }

    public void setReservationdate(Date reservationdate) {
        this.reservationdate = reservationdate;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Reservation> getReservationList() {
        return reservationList;
    }

    public void setReservationList(List<Reservation> reservationList) {
        this.reservationList = reservationList;
    }

    public Reservation getLoginid() {
        return loginid;
    }

    public void setLoginid(Reservation loginid) {
        this.loginid = loginid;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (reservationid != null ? reservationid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {

        if (!(object instanceof Reservation)) {
            return false;
    }
        Reservation other = (Reservation) object;
        if ((this.reservationid == null && other.reservationid != null) || (this.reservationid != null && !this.reservationid.equals(other.reservationid))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "entity.Reservation[ reservationid=" + reservationid + " ]";
}

}
```

How should i insert data into this table???
my table

ReservationID   VARCHAR(10)
loginid         VARCHAR(20) (foreign key from members table)
TourID          VARCHAR(10) (foreign key from tourpackage table)
ReservationDate DATE

Comment: To make it clear - you're using an ORM mapper and you are still interested in entering data directly using SQL? Or you want to persist an entity?

Comment: i want to persist an entity

Comment: From standalone Java code, EJB, CDI bean? What is your environment, how are you obtaining EntityManager (are you using one?)

Comment: im doing this JSF. i want to persist an reservation entity from my session bean, so the parameter i should pass in is a reservation object right? but this entity class does not have variable for the loginid and tourid... And the EntityManager is in my session bean

Comment: this entity class is generated by netbeans, from the database i created in netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about the Framework are you using , just by seeing the Entity

If you are using EJB3

You can make use of `EntityManager` and call the `Persist(entity)` method to save the entity

If you are using raw Hibernate

Get `Session` and use `save` method

Session -> org.hibernate.Session

Comment: i m going to call the Persist method. this is my entity class, but it does not have the variable for the table. the bottom part are variables that should be in the table

Comment: Do you see @Column name = "Something". That is the column name in table. The corresponding variable in java is declared in the class.
The Entity is nothing but a mapping of a Table
The attributes of Entity are the Columns in the table

Comment: o... finally found the error... i did something stupid...
thx for all your replies

Comment: Add a new answer and , put your mistake/correction in that. After 2 days u can accept that as answer